# This bed has not been slept in ..... ? "for a long time by anybody" vs "by anybody for a long time"

Tags: prepositions, passive-voice, prepositional-phrases

> This bed has not been slept in **for a long time by anybody**.
>
> This bed has not been slept in **by anybody for a long time**.

Which is grammatically correct?

Or, is there a difference between the two sentences?

Comment: At times, I don't understand what's so exciting to make a simple thing the most perplexed one! *Nobody has slept on this bed since long...* what problem you or the author could have with this! Phew!

Comment: The difference is merely in the word order.

Comment: @MaulikV *Since long* isn't Standard English. Maybe it's used in India, but not in AmE or BrE (I checked both COCA and BNC).

Comment: @userr2684291 - That may be true, but Maulik's larger point holds: _No one has slept in this bed for a long time_ would be an improvement over either of the two sentences given by the OP.

Comment: @J.R. (: I don't disagree.

Comment: Which is grammatically correct? Or is there a difference between the two sentences?

Comment: @SuwonKim They're both grammatical, and there's probably a negligible difference in emphasis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, they are both grammatically correct.

The only difference is stylistic emphasis

> **for a long time** by anybody

emphasizes the amount of time, "***by anybody***" is repetitive.
Consider

> This bed has not been slept in **for a long time**.
>   This bed has not been slept in **by anybody**.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind explanation. But how can I adopt your answer? I want to adopt your answer, but honestly, I don't know.

Comment: Usually when you Accept and answer, you upvote and then click on the checkmark (next to "Consider")

Comment: Thank you, but where is the word "Consider"? I just clicked the word "votes? at the end of Answer. Is that correct?

Comment: Its to the left of the question.

Comment: @SuwonKim You can click on the check mark sign just below the down-vote arrow. By doing that, the sign turns into green which shows the question has an accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

I can only hear the first sentence as a type of redundancy used for emphasis, and in fact I would be likely to punctuate it as follows:

> This bed has not been slept in for a long time—by anybody.

However, in the second sentence, the addition of "for a long time" actually changes the meaning of the sentence. The following sentence means that the bed has never been slept in:

> This bed has not been slept in by anybody.

So, the following sentence changes the meaning from *never* to *for a long time*:

> This bed has not been slept in by anybody for a long time.

Because of this, it sounds much more idiomatic to me to have it in this order (rather than *for a long time by anybody*), although both constructions are grammatical. You could leave out "by anybody" in this sentence, too, without losing any meaning; however, you may want to emphasize people, for some reason. (Perhaps mice have been sleeping in it.)

As others have pointed out, a better form might be to say the following:

> No one has slept in this bed for a long time.

However, the speaker or writer may have legitimate reasons for wanting to use "this bed" as the subject.